# Mount a NTFS drive with Junction point

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

My desktop has 3 physical hard drives and I dual boot between Win7 and Kubuntu 14.04.  I have a 250G drive with Windows on it, a 200GB drive for Linux and a 1TB drive for data.  When I set the computer up originally I didn't have Ubuntu, and I mounted the 1TB drive to C:\Users using a NTFS Junction.  So when I boot into Windows D:\ and C:\Users are the same thing.

I can't get the 1TB drive to be mountable in Ubuntu though.  When I go to the Partition Editor it shows up as a drive, but if I click on it, I can't mount it.  If I right click on it, I get the option to create a new File Partition Table.  I have yet to do that because I don't want to mess the drive up in Windows.  The drive shows up as 'loop' device which I read means it's a file with a file system in it.

Is there a way I can make this drive mountable in linux without removing the junction in Windows?